# set and get data from service angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I am using angular 5
my scenario is from one component im setting the data in service and from another component i'm getting that data|

Component- 1:

```
makeUser(row){
  this.agentsService.setSelectedAgentData(row); // setting the data (row) in agentsService.
  const mrf =  this.modalService.open(MakeUserComponent);    
}
```

Service:
declaring the varible in class.

```
public selectedData:any = {};
```

setter and getter methods are as below

```
  setSelectedAgentData(selectedTableRowData){
    this.selectedData = selectedTableRowData;
  }
  getSelectedAgentData(){
    return this.selectedData;
  }
```

Component - 2:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userDetails = this.agentsService.getSelectedAgentData();
    this.roles = this.agentsService.getRolesList();
  }
```

Here the selectedData value is an empty object when I call the method this.agentsService.getSelectedAgentData() from component -2

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could it be because you're calling it from within `ngOnInit()`? It means that you're calling it too early, before its value is changed from component 1

Comment: try logging in `makeUser` and in `ngOnInit` of comp 2. The log in makeUser should log before that of component 2

Comment: the component 2 will be loaded when the  this.modalService.open(MakeUserComponent);  gets called from component-1

Comment: Are you sure component2 is lazy-loaded? That'd be the only way that its code isn't executed immediately. Just `console.log()` in component2's `ngOnInit` to make sure you're not calling `getSelectedAgentData()` too early...

Comment: Agreed with @JeremyThille . @Shikhathakur does you're loading both component together, and setting data in component-1 later? I'd say this scenario can be handled by using shareable `BehaviourSubject` observable and placing subscriber wherever you won't to listen to changes. Checkout [this article](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/) could help you. Or you can consider adding stackblitz / plunker. I'd love to jump in

Comment: Where is `agentService` provided? For them to share an instance, it'll need to be in the correct `providers` array

Answer (score 2):

You can use Subject (rxjs library) for this purpose. So Subject can generate data on the one hand. And on the other hand, you can subscribe to changes in any place.
You service would look like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class YourService {

  public selectedData: Subject<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.selectedData = new Subject();
  }

  generateSelectedAgentData(row: string) {
    this.selectedData.next(row);
  }
}
```

In your first Component:

```
makeUser(row){
  this.agentsService.generateSelectedAgentData(row);
  const mrf =  this.modalService.open(MakeUserComponent);    
}
```

In your second Component:

```
constructor(private ys: YourService){
  this.ys.selectedData.subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.userDetails = data;
    });
}
```